# Dimension of algebraic variety if we know dimension of irreducible components

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a bit of trouble with finding the dimension of an algebraic set. In general I know that this is the supremum of the integers $n$ such that there exists a chain $Z_0 \subset Z_1 \subset ... \subset Z_n$ of distinct irreducible closed subsets.

In the exercise that I'm making, I know that the algebraic set that I'm working with is reducible. I also know that the dimension of every irreducible component of the algebraic set is $2$. Does this imply that the dimension of the algebraic set is $2$?

This doesn't seem right to me. Hopefully someone can help me out.

Comment: There exists a chain $Z_0 \subset Z_1 \subset \ldots \subset Z_n$ of what?

Comment: @PaulK I edited my post!

Comment: Okay, and now: Why do you expect the dimension to be $0$? If your variety is irreducible and every irreducible component has dimension $2$, why should your variety have dimension $0$?

Comment: You're right this isn't right, the dimension of this set must be at least 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the dimension of any algebraic set will be the maximum of the dimensions of the irreducible components. This is because any chain $Z_0 \subset \dots \subset Z_n$ of irreducible closed subsets will all lie inside some irreducible component, by the definition of irreducibility.

This means that the dimension of your algebraic set is $2$, not $0$.

As a further note, this is even true for closed subsets and not irreducible components: if $Z$ is the union of two closed subsets $X$ and $Y$, then the dimension of $Z$ is the maximum of $\dim X$ and $\dim Y$.

Comment: This really helps me out! Thank you!